# Fetch second largest date with a group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure is like this

```
catName    class   age
-------------------
AAA        4       19
AAA        3       14
AAA        3       12
AAA        3       9
BBB        7       12
BBB        6       12
BBB        7       17
CCC        8       10
DDD        9       10
DDD        9       11
```

The result that I want is to get the second largest age for group by catName and class.
So the result should be

```
AAA 3 14
BBB 7 12
DDD 9 10
```

Please help me find query for MySQL

Comment: why are rows with one per group in catname and class in the result, if you are looking for the second largest?

Comment: `Order BY age DESC, class ASC`

Comment: You said 'get the 2nd largest age for group by CatName and class' - but AAA, 4 and BBB, 6 don't have a 2nd largest, yet you still list them in your output. So you have multiple rules - therefore I think this is beyond MySQL and should be done at the scripting (PHP) level. And you should at least show what query you're trying - as is, it looks like you're asking for free (home)work.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  It is rather tricky.

Comment: For the special case of second largest, you can use select max where not in select max, but a canonical solution is more advisable- as described in the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but here is one method:

```
select catname, class,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(age order by age desc), ',', 2), ',' -1)
             else max(age)
        end) as age
from t
group by catname, class;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are actually after - your example output doesn't match your stated requirements.

The query below will return the 2nd-highest age for each group if one exists.  If there is only one age for the group, nothing will be returned.

```
select  a.class,
        a.catName,
        max( age ) as second_highest_age
from    table1 as a
        left join
        (
            /* get the highest age for this class/catName */
            select  class,
                    catName,
                    max( age ) as maxAge
            from    table1
            group by class,
                    catName
        ) as b
        on a.class = b.class 
        and a.catName = b.catName
/* filter out records where the age is equal to the max age for this group */
/* this will leave the second-highest age in each group (if one exists) */
where   a.age <> b.maxAge
group by a.class,
        a.catName
```

SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e4df/4)

Comment: Oh. Right. If there is only one record in group by then nothing should be returned. I will check your query and will respond. Thanks. Updated the expected result section on my question.

Comment: Works after changing the last b.catName to a.catName. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for the typo. Glad you got it working, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Its not working properly.... i checked deeply and the results are incorrect. Its giving the second largest even when both the records have same class and catName

Comment: I don't think I understand.  Are you saying that if there are two records with the exact same class, catName and age you want one of those two records returned as the second largest?

Comment: Rec 1 -> AAA    4    23 ||| Rec 2 -> AAA    4    19||| Rec 3 -> AAA   6   12||| Then the result should be AAA    6   12. But its returning record 2 now.

Comment: Oh I see. You want the second highest age for each class, regardless of catName?

Comment: Hang on, I still don't get it. Why should record 3 be returned in your example?

Comment: No. since the records are group by catname and class, group by record which has second highest age should be in my result. so since record 1 and 2 are same as per the group by condition, and max age of record 1 and 2 is more than the age of record 3, record 3 should has the second largest age.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133938/discussion-between-alex-and-romhail).